# How do I link a Yarn module to a different repo's Docker container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, npm, yarnpkg

I'm struggling to do a module link to a second repo's Docker container. For context I have a container with a React application inside it called launch-control-admin. That project makes use of a yarn module called @company-name/business-checks-client which I need to do some work on locally. The issue is the launch-control-admin container isn't seeing any of my local changes and I'm stumped at this point on how to connect them together.

I have tried the following in the Docker Compose file where it would copy in the repos files on mount as a volume yet the changes don't appear, which is odd.

launch-control-admin.docker-compose

```js
version: '3'
services:
  launch_control_admin:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NPM_TOKEN
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - NPM_TOKEN
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ../business-checks-client:/usr/src/app/node_modules/@company-name/business-checks-client
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want volumes from host machine to live refresh on you react app running inside of docker container, few things are necessary. You have to `:delegate` whatever you need to be getting fresh data from the host, get rid of node_modules (which you did) that would get delegated with it and make sure that the builder is set to use polling.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  launch_control_admin:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NPM_TOKEN
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - NPM_TOKEN
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:delegated # <=======
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ../business-checks-client:/usr/src/app/node_modules/@company-name/business-checks-client  # <=== Probably even here
```

I don't know what you are using to run react, but for create-react-app you need to set `environment: - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` for craco it's `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`

I hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Much appreciated will give it a try later